# Python Pandas right fill values based on groups

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replicate a "right fill" excel-like function which fills the values right till the next value is not null/nan/empty. This "right-fill" exercise is only to be done if the value in the immediate following row in not empty or "nan". Furthermore, this has to be done for every group. I have the following pandas dataframe dataset. My current input table is "have". My output table is "want".

I am just a beginner in python. So any help would be appreciated.
Also for those who would like this operation to be undertaken on a by group operation, data as follows:
Table "have" as follows with grouping field "groups":

```
import pandas as pd
    have = pd.DataFrame({ \
    "groups": pd.Series(["group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2"]) \
    ,"0": pd.Series(["abc","1","something here","abc2","1","something here"]) \
    ,"1": pd.Series(["","2","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"2": pd.Series(["","3","something here","","3","something here"]) \
    ,"3": pd.Series(["something","1","something here","something","1","something here"]) \
    ,"4": pd.Series(["","2","something here","","2","something here"]) \
    ,"5": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"6": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"7": pd.Series(["cdf","5","something here","mnop","5","something here"]) \
    ,"8": pd.Series(["","6","something here","","6","something here"]) \
    ,"9": pd.Series(["xyz","1","something here","xyz","1","something here"]) \
    })
```

Table "want" with grouping fields "groups":

```
import pandas as pd
    want = pd.DataFrame({ \
    "groups": pd.Series(["group1","group1","group1","group2","group2","group2"]) \
    ,"0": pd.Series(["abc","1","something here","anything","1","something here"]) \
    ,"1": pd.Series(["abc","2","something here"," anything ","2","something here"]) \
    ,"2": pd.Series(["abc","3","something here"," anything ","3","something here"]) \
    ,"3": pd.Series(["something","1","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"4": pd.Series(["something ","2","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"5": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"6": pd.Series(["","","something here","","","something here"]) \
    ,"7": pd.Series(["cdf","5","something here","mnop","5","something here"]) \
    ,"8": pd.Series(["cdf ","6","something here"," mnop ","6","something here"]) \
    ,"9": pd.Series(["xyz","1","something here","xyz","1","something here"]) \
    })
```

I tried to use this code, but I am still trying to familiar myself with `groupby` and `apply` statements:

```
grouped=have.groupby('groups') 
have.groupby('groups').apply(lambda g: have.loc[g].isnull() )
#cond = have.loc[1].isnull() | have.loc[1].ne('')
want.loc[0, cond] = want.loc[0, cond].str.strip().replace('', None)
want
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fill(df):
    df = df.copy()
    i0, i1 = df.index[0], df.index[1]
    cond = have.loc[i1].isnull() | have.loc[i1].ne('')
    df.loc[i0, cond] = df.loc[i0, cond].str.strip().replace('', None)
    return df


have.groupby('groups', group_keys=False).apply(fill)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you piRSquared. U genius :)